# How to change the start time of track in Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, imovie

I'm exporting a project from iMovie to Final Cut Pro X.

It's really a mess, but working patiently on the project on FCPX can achieve some better results... in any case, during the exporting many videos and sounds chenged their start and end time.

So, to give an example, if I had an audio of me reading the sentences "Hi all, how are you? Today I'm not fine because I'm getting crazy", and in iMovie I had cut the 
"how are you" sentence, then in FCPX it gives me the "I'm getting crazy" part of the track.

So I have two question:

1. do you know how to fix this? Is there a known issue? I searched a lot but I couln't find anything!
2. in case there is not a solution to this problem, is there a FAST way to change the start time and the end time of a track?

I tought it was simple to do with the "open in timeline" menu, but it is not possible.

When I open the audio track in the timeline, the active part is eveidenced, but appartenly there is no way to MOVE the part I want to use...

I hope I made myself understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the trim tool (keyboard shortcut "t").

Comment: is there a way to speed up the trimming (so that with one move I skip, for instance, one minute instead of one second)?

Comment: zoom out of the timeline?

Comment: yes that's a way. Then I found also one more efficient: after typing 't' you can manually enter the time shift typink '+' or '-' and then the number of seconds you want to shift. it works! Thanks again.